# Why does my elementary OS Freya show an Ubuntu logo?

Tags: settings, themes, ubuntu

I've only had Freya on my computer for 3 days. I'm guessing it's something to do with the Ubuntu updates which changed my logo. So far nothing more than this logo has changed, Grub still calls it elementary OS

I'm sure I didn't change the update settings. I am using Moka icon theme.

Is there any way that I can change the logo back?

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Logo in Switchboard]

Comment: what icons theme do you use?

Comment: i use Moka. Oh ok... so it's the icon theme that changed my logo

Comment: Then please add an answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Logo changed because you use Moka icon theme.

If theme was installed from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~moka/+archive/ubuntu/stable), logo can be returned to default by following command in the terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/.icons/Moka/48x48/places && ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary/places/48/distributor-logo.svg ~/.icons/Moka/48x48/places/distributor-logo.svg
```