# missing elementary "e" logo on startup and shut down display

Tags: release-freya, updates, startup

After upgrading a fresh installed elementary OS freya 0.3.1 64bit with apt-get dist-upgrade on start up (booting the computer) and shut-down instead of the "e" logo appears a fast running list of commands on display. The elementary desktop seems not to be affected.

Note: I already looked at [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/why-does-my-elementary-os-freya-show-an-ubuntu-logo) question. But it does not affect me, because in the info panel in system settings the "e" logo appears correctly on my computer.

I remember when I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` during the upgrade process I was confronted with a simple graphical choice within the terminal that stated something like "there is a new grub version but your existing grub version was modified" giving me the option to "use version from packet manager" "use existing version" and "show the difference". I tried showing the difference but did not understand what the difference is. So I choose to use the new version from the packet manager since I wanted to upgrade my installation.

I assume maybe I should have stayed with the than existing (old) modified version of grub? Maybe the modification was just to include the "e" logo instead of running messages too fast to read?

**If so my question is:**
1. does this affect any more than the start-up display?
2. How can I revert to the modified grub without reinstall the whole elementary OS?

Maybe it is of interest that between fresh install and update/upgrade I did only one thing: I changed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in the file elementary.list the broken update links pointing to `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu freya main`  to `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty main` and in patches.list from  "`http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu freya main`" to  "`http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu trusty main`" since no subdirectory `freya` exists on ppa.launchpad.net and Freya is build on Trusty. (see the answer to my question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/recent-change-in-elementary-os-repository-structure) and the selection options given [here](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable))

Note 2: My question was down-voted. I would like to know why in order to improve my question. And still would like to have answer to my two-fold question above. Especially the second part on how to revert to original start-up screen.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `cat /etc/default/grub | grep LINUX_DEFAULT`

Comment: Same problem here. You're not alone! :) although I'm not sure what could be the cause of the probleme in my case...

Comment: @elmato Here comes the output of cat /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" ( sorry for delay, my internet provider had connection problems during the weekend.)